# override no-display with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following div in my cshtml (Razor) file, which by default does not display. I want to override the no-display and make it visible using jquery in the associated javascript file, but it does not work. I am calling $(uiElements.divConfirmationMessage).show(), but noting happens. Any advice or help is appreciated.

```html
 <p id="divConfirmationMessage" class="success-message message no-display">
                <span style="width:50px;" class="fl">
                    <span class="icon successGreen"></span>
                    <span> @Session["message"]</span>
                    @*<span> Hello From Hugh</span>*@
                </span>
                @*<span class="icon close" style="padding-left:20px" id="spnReserveAcctCloseIcon"></span>*@
            </p>
```

Comment: What is inside `uiElements.divConfirmationMessage` expression ? `$("#divConfirmationMessage").show()` should work

Comment: Calling the `show` method will add an inline style `style="display: block;` to the element, which will override your css class definition. So your code should work fine. Here is a working jsfiddle http://jsbin.com/biliponoco/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but as of my understanding, 'no-display' class has style to hide the element. You can removeClass 'no-display' to show the element as follows.

```
$('#divConfirmationMessage').removeClass('no-display');
```

Let me know if I understood wrong

Comment: No you understood right, but I tried that command and it did not work.

Comment: Can you please share 'no-display' class style?

Comment: '    .no-display, .hiddenTR {
 display: none; 
}    '

Comment: Okay, seems to be div element being overriding with some CSS property. Check css of div element in the browser inspect element. try putting 'display: block !important '